# Why am I getting this weird bug with only a type error and not a zeroDivision error?

Tags: java, exception

So I really have 2 questions. The 1st is, in Java how do I do the equivalent of this python code:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input('Enter num1: '))
        num2 = int(input('Enter num2: '))
        print(str(num1) + ' / ' + str(num2) + ' = ' + str(num1 / num2))
        break

    except:
        print('ERROR')
```

What I want is the program to say to the user "No you did this wrong! Now do it again until you get it right." I tried writing this in java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TryCatch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter num1: ");
                int num1 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter num2: ");
                int num2 = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + num1 / num2);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println(e.getCause());
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now this does exactly what I want it too when num2 is equal to 0. For reference, here's the output when that happens and I kill the process after the 1st iteration:

```
Enter num1: 5
Enter num2: 0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
null
/ by zero
Enter num1: 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

However when either num1 or num2 is a String, java prints the following 3 lines in an infinite loop until I kill the process:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
null
null
```

This obviously means that I'm doing something wrong, but for the life of me I don't know why the catch block keeps running in an infinite loop with a type error but not with zeroDivision error...
So my 2 specific questions are:

1. How do I achieve what I've described that I want to do? i.e. make the program tell the user "No you did this wrong! Now do it again until you get it right."
2. What is the reason that this is an incorrect solution? i.e. why does the catch block run in an infinite loop when there's a type error but not a zeroDivision error?

EDIT:
Since I can only accept 1 answer, I wanted to specifically thank @rgettman for explaining how the nextInt() method causes my particular problem and @Alireza Dastyar for giving me what I think is a more elegant solution since it changes where the exception is thrown from instead of sort of cleaning up the messy input after the fact which means that you have give dummy input when that particular exception isn't thrown.

Comment: When `nextInt()` throws `InputMismatchException`, no characters have been consumed from the input, so calling it again will fail again. You need to call `next()` or `nextLine()` to consume the bad input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution never gets to the division by zero.  When you type in something that `nextInt()` can't handle, that method throws an `InputMismatchException` before the execution reaches the division expression.

Also, when a `Scanner` method that consumes input throws that exception, it doesn't consume the offending input, the loop repeats, and `nextInt()` throws an exception on the *same* input, causing the infinite loop.

The [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) javadocs:

> This method will throw `InputMismatchException` if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below. If the translation is successful, the scanner advances past the input that matched.

1. In the `catch` block, print the message to the user to try again.
2. Call `input.next()` in the `catch` block to consume the incorrect input and advance to the next token.

You will need to carefully handle the input when the incorrect input is the first input; there may be *2* tokens of input to skip in this case.

Consider calling `hasNextInt()` to determine if there is an integer to be parsed on the input.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm pretty used to python so the quirks with the Scanner class all seem really un-intuitive to me.
By any chance, do you know exactly why the nextInt() method does this? I can't think of a situation where this would be useful.